# Referencing Enum C++ Unreal

Tags: c++, enums, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

I have created an Enum Class in Unreal C++

```
#include "GroundDirection.generated.h"

UENUM(BlueprintType)
enum UGroundDirection
{
     BOTTOM = 0,
     LEFT = 1,
     TOP = 2,
     RIGHT = 3
};
```

In C# or Java I could instantiate a copy of this Enum doing something like this:

```
GroundDirection groundDirection = GroundDirection.BOTTOM;
```

I thought I could do something similar with Unreal C++

```
UGroundDirection groundDirection = UGroundDirection.BOTTOM;
```

However when I do this I get the following error:

> error C2228: left of '.BOTTOM' must have class/struct/union

How to I instantiate Enums in light of this error?

Comment: `U` is for UObjects, `E` is for enum.

Answer (score 1):

> I have created an Enum Class in Unreal C++

No, you didn't. You just created a C-style enum.
Also, the [UE++ coding standard](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Development/CodingStandard/index.html) states that an enum should have an `E` as a prefix.

So your declaration should actually look like this:

```
#include "GroundDirection.generated.h"

UENUM(BlueprintType)
enum class EGroundDirection
{
     BOTTOM = 0,
     LEFT = 1,
     TOP = 2,
     RIGHT = 3
};
```

To access the members of the enum, you access them like they are static members of a class:

```
EGroundDirection direction = EGroundDirection::BOTTOM;
```

This is, because you are not accessing a member of an instance, but a declaration which is always done by using `::` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

`BOTTOM` isn't a class but an integer. Moreover, `UGroundDirection` isn't a class/struct/union but an `enum`, and hence it is kind of considered as a namespace. You shall use `::` instead of `.`

To solve your problem, you shall simply remove `UGroundDirection` from `UGroundDirection groundDirection = UGroundDirection.BOTTOM;` and replace it with: `int groundDirection = UGroundDirection::BOTTOM`

That's all!

Comment: Better don't use int. UGroundDirection groundDirection = UGroundDirection::BOTTOM; is perfectly ok and fits new enum class syntax.

Comment: @AlexZaharov Both actually work perfectly, and I don't the inconvenient of using either of them. But in general, `int` is used to extract data from an `enum`

Comment: This way is supposed bad and old. Mixing int and enum, that's why "enum class" was introduced. In new projects I do enum class to force stop that hidden conversion. It makes more problems then solves when using optimizing compiler (any new). I can imagine cases when logic will break. For example, int is 16 bit on 8 or 16 bit machines (microcontrollers) while enum constant may have big values. Any way, my point is, better avoid that fake convenience as good practice without real need.

Comment: @AlexZaharov I agree with you in this case.

Comment: But using both is correct. However, I suggest using `int32_t` or `int64_t` if you really want to use `int` as whole.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can use either the "namespace-enum" style or "enum class" style. Both of them will limit the elements in specific domain.

Well, some comments say I didn't proveide the solution.

You can try

```cpp
#include "GroundDirection.generated.h"

UENUM(BlueprintType)
enum class EGroundDirection
{
     BOTTOM = 0,
     LEFT = 1,
     TOP = 2,
     RIGHT = 3
};
```

or

```cpp
#include "GroundDirection.generated.h"

UENUM(BlueprintType)
namespace EGroundDirection
{
    enum EGroundDirection
    {
         BOTTOM = 0,
         LEFT = 1,
         TOP = 2,
         RIGHT = 3
    };
};
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question at hand, only clarifies terminology.